# How can I debug very slow commit times?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I believe that some commits on our database are taking up to 10 seconds to finish, for simple 1 row inserts.  My evidence is that I'm seeing some duplicate orders a very small percentage of the time, even though the C# application code that creates the orders does a check in the database for duplicates first, and rejects the request if it finds one.

My theory is that the first order is in limbo during the slow commit, and when the duplicate order is created, the duplicate check passes because the previous order has not yet been committed to the database.  I have a few questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, how could I verify that this is what's happening?
3. What would be the most likely causes?
4. What steps should I take to try to determine the cause?

So far, I have tried looking at the "Performance Monitor," but am not sure what I should be looking for and don't see anything relevant.  Similarly, it's not clear to me how to find the relevant log files, or if I need to turn on additional logging, or how to do that.

Comment: The number of reasons isn't small but I would start by: [1] examining execution plans and [2] by checking of there is a blocking chain (2.1 - using [Activity Monitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518(v=sql.100).aspx), section Processes, columns Blocked By and Head Blocker). If you need more help please add details (ex. execution plans in XML format).

Comment: Although slow queries due to suboptimal plans or blocking may expose the issue, the root cause of duplicate orders is a race condition.  You have a race condition in the default `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level if your pattern is `IF NOT EXISTS...INSERT`.

Comment: @DanGuzman Exactly.  That would make perfect sense.  How can find what my current `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level is for this table?  Or is it db-level configuration variable?  And what is the correct setting if I want to make such race conditions impossible?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is possible, especially for application being used by multiple concurrent user at the same time.

if you can reproduce that on local environment. You can run sql profiler to see if that is the case. Or you might need to add some debug information around the code block that create the order.

It is hard to give comment on the cause without knowing how you implement the code (e.g. are you using sql stored procedure to checking order exist and insert or you use some ORM tool like entity framework, have you use transaction and locking already etc)

Also, if a single record takes more than 10 seconds to insert, i would recommend you to fix that, since it is just taking too long.

Comment: Thanks.  The duplicate check is done using an ORM, and I don't _think_ there is locking.  It was written by someone else, and I am not that knowledgeable about sqlserver, so please excuse the lack of info.  I _strongly_ agree with your point about 10 seconds being too long, but I am at a loss about where to start to debug that.  Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: One method is to use the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level and execute the query/queries in the same transaction.  Another is to use an explicit transaction along with the `UPDLOCK` and `HOLDLOCK` locking hints to provide serializable behavior.  Post your SQL code if you need a concrete example.